# How to give constraints to a tableview when tableview cell is on xib. And table view is on storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, constraints, ios-autolayout

I have a table view on storyboard i.e. FirstStory.Storyboard. And for this tableview I have created a table view cell on xib file where I give size to its width as per my current storyboard width. But when I launch my app it runs fine on the landscape position. But when I rotate it in the portrait mode. Width is unable to show the all item which I placed in tableviewcell.xib. How we mutually combine these two item in storyboard (table view on storyboard while cell on xib). Which follow a single constraints with above condition.

Comment: Since you are using storyboard, why don't you just use a prototype cell for your cell and get rid of the nib file

Comment: Some time its requirement. Let say you have a table view which is having multiple section or different design on each cell. You cann't proceed with just a static cell on your storyboard.

Comment: Not a static cell, prototype cells. You can have as many different prototype cells as you like, each with a different reuse identifier and custom UITableViewCell subclass. There is no need to use nib files if you are using storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

UITableViewCell's contentView property is always the size of the cell. So you have to setup the constraints of your UI components in the xib file with the Cell's contentView properly. The issue you are facing must be because you did not setup these constraints properly.

To see which views or constraints have been placed wrong, use the XCode's 'Debug View Hierarcy' feature.

Launch it from here

[image]

Run your app, navigate to your tableView, then press the above button to launch the view debugger. It provides very good insight into your constraints and where the issue may lie

Comment: Its good to see constraints at live when app is running. But how we resolve this issue. I am looking for an option for which i can proceed for my table view whose cell's width is 1024 in landescape while in portrait is only 768. But data is still like landescape and data is truncated.